# How to autofill HTML form?

Tags: html, forms

**Stage**

Suppose an HTML page in some URL (i.e. http://mysite.com/registry.html) and this HTML file contains a HTML form, like this:

```
<form action="/">
  <input name="firstname">
  <input name="lastname">
  <textarea name="message"></textarea>
</form>
```

If I want to *prefill* this form how can I do this?

Maybe I thought that I can *prefill* this form on URL request. But I do not know if it is possible.

**Restriction**

- I do not have access to `mysite.com` server nor `registry.html`.

Comment: Do you have access to the client or do you mean like XSRF?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with some JavaScript sorcery, load the page (http://example.com/registry.html) via AJAX:

```
function loadPage()
{
    jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://example.com/registry.html",
    success: successFn
});
                            
}

function successFn(data)
{
var result=jQuery(data).find("#idOfTheInput").html()
//modify the default value
//re attach the input into the html
//render the html
                            
}
```

The rest is up to you; dig into the dom and put the values you want.

Comment: Render it where?  On a different site:  Then why pull a form with no values?  On the original site:  That sounds like an XSS to me.  Not sure what the OP really wants though.

Answer (score -2):

You can try to pass parameters by the url.

Something like this:

http://test.com?param1

This url is passing a parameter (param1), so you can set up the members of this form to be able to receive these parameters.

Regards,

Otacon.